# Where in the Android Source are SMS sent and received

Tags: android, sms

In the Android 4.4 source, what Classes are responsible for handling incoming and outgoing SMS?
I'm currently not finding the relevant classes.
Alternatively, a good documentation would be valuable.

Comment: The ones with sms in the name

Answer (score 0):

The [Telephony](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.html) content provider (the "SMS Provider") allows apps to read and write SMS and MMS messages on the device. You can read this [documentation](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html) about SMS apps in KitKat.

Also, you can view this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19751652/4195406) about the usage of sending SMS in Android 4.4.