# Send sms from default sms application

Tags: android, sms, send

I am trying to send a SMS from my application that already set as default SMS application. I have tried to send using SmsManager, but it does not work.
Here is what I have tried:

```
SmsManager smsMan = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsMan.sendTextMessage(Name, null, body, null, null);
```

This approach works when my application was not set as default app, but it didn't when my app is the default one.
Is there any other approach to send a SMS from inside the default SMS application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19560323/send-sms-message-using-non-default-sms-app-on-android-4-4

Comment: When you're testing as the default SMS app, are you sure your message isn't exceeding the character limit for a single-part message?

Comment: It should use the set default SMS app. My question is, how are you trying to determine that it is not using your own SMS app to send the message.

Comment: @MikeM. no, I just trying to send a single piece of word.

Comment: How are you determining that it's not working? Is the recipient just not receiving the message? Is the outgoing message just not showing in another SMS app? Is it throwing an Exception? Also, are you sure the address is correct? That is, the first argument in the method call, `Name`.

Comment: @MikeM.as you already mention, the recipient did not received the message. i have not check the address. btw, does my aprroach already correct?

Comment: Yeah, sending text messages is the same for both default and non-default apps, so that should work for ya, provided everything is correct; i.e., the address, the permissions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code to send message

```
String number = "12346556";  // The number on which you want to send SMS  
     startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromParts("sms", number, null)));
```

Comment: The OP is asking about their app acting as the default SMS app, for which they need to use `SmsManager`. Your code is not appropriate to that requirement, as it is meant to open another app to handle the message. Furthermore, `ACTION_VIEW` isn't really what you want in that case, anyway.

Comment: Else try SEND_TO for your purpose...                                                'String phoneNumber = "9999999999";
String smsBody = "This is an SMS!";
 
// Add the phone number in the data
Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + phoneNumber);
// Create intent with the action and data
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
// smsIntent.setData(uri); // We just set the data in the constructor above
// Set the message
smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", smsBody);
 
startActivity(smsIntent);'

Comment: Again, this really isn't pertinent to the OP's situation.

Comment: @raasesh I've tried that approach, it didn't work either